# Unable to load the data from back-end to ant design form field using formRef.current.setFieldsValue

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to load some data from the back-end server and populate it into From Item input using the setFieldsValue. I'm using formRef.current.setFieldsValue in a DrawerFrom from the ant-design-pro template. [refer here](https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/modal-form). I have reproduced the issue in code sandbox link.(https://codesandbox.io/s/drawer-biaodan-forked-7cxeb)